# Styles are not going into effect

Tags: php, html, css

Here is my content.php page:

```
<div class="section">
    <button class="create-note">Create Note</button>
        </div>
        <div class="section">
        <div class="list-of-notes">
        <div class="intro-message add-note-message welcome-note">
            <p>Don't have any notes yet? <a href="">Add one here</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my lists.php page:

```
<?php
require_once "header.php";
?>
<div class="lists-content">
    <div class="note">
        <p class="header-note">
            <!--Add elipsis-->
        </div>
        <p class="center-note note-content"></p>
        <p class="footer-note dates">
            <!--Sorting and iltering based on modification and dates-->
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my header.php which links to all four of my stylesheets I'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@300;400;500;600;700;800&family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&family=Rubik:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;1,400;1,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d5b1d340c5.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css?v=<?php echo time(); ?>">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=<?php echo time(); ?>">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/local-styles.css?v=<?php echo time(); ?>">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css?v=<?php echo time(); ?>">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Homepage</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="left">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-bars" id="bars"></i>
                <h1 class="logo">Notebook</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="center">
                <input type="text" class='searchbar' placeholder='Search Notes'>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <div class="bell-wrapper">
                    <p class="notifications">8</p>
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-bell"></i>
                </div>
                <i class="fa-solid fa-gear"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar" id="navbar">
            <div class="navbar-items">
            <a href="homepage.php">Home</p>
            <a href="lists.php">Lists</p>
            <a href="">Editor</p>
            <a href="">Settings</p>
            </div>
            <div class="logout-login options"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
```

Here is my styles.css and local-styles.css:

```
.header .left {
    width:150px;
    height:100%;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
}

.left .fa-bars {
    color:#01000a;
    padding:12px;
    cursor:pointer;
    border-radius:2px;
    margin:10px;
}

.left .fa-bars:hover {
    background:#efefef;
}

#bars {
    display:none;
}

.left h1.logo {
    font-family:"Inter", sans-serif;
    font-weight:500;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:25px;
    color: rgb(1, 0, 3);
    margin:20px;
}

.header .center {
    flex:1;
    height:100%;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.center input.searchbar {
    border: 1px solid #f7f2f2;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 16px;
    /*width: 900px;*/
    width:100%;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow:2px 2px 12px 2px #fffcfc;
}

.center input.searchbar::placeholder {
    font-family: 'Roboto',"Poppins", sans-serif;
    color:rgb(228, 220, 220);
    font-size: 16px;
}

.content .section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    /*background: #efefef;*/
    margin: 1px;
}

.section .create-note {
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    padding:16px;
    border-radius:2px;
    background:#efefef;
    /*cursor:pointer;*/
    font-family:"Roboto",sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    margin:10px;
    box-shadow:2px 2px 12px 2px #fffbfb;
    width:200px;
}

.section .create-note:hover {
    background:#5558f5;
    color:#fff;
}

.section .list-of-notes {
    width:500px;
    height:400px;
    margin-left:10px;
    position:relative;
}

.list-of-notes .intro-message > p {
    font-family:"Roboto",sans-serif;
}

.list-of-notes .intro-message a {
    font-family:"Roboto",sans-serif;
    color: rgb(124, 100, 255);
    text-decoration: none;
}


.header .right {
    width:100px;
    height:100%;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:flex-end;
}

.right .bell-wrapper {
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    border-radius:2px;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    position:relative;
}

.bell-wrapper .notifications {
    position:absolute;
    top:-5px;
    right:-5px;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    border-radius:50%;
    font-family:"Roboto",sans-serif;
    padding:2px;
    font-size:14px;
    background:#5558f5;
    color:#fff;
}

.right i {
    margin:10px;
    padding:10px;
    border-radius:4px;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#01000a;
}

.right i:hover {
    background:#efefef;
}

.sidebar .navbar-items {
    width:100%;
    height:60%;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
}

.navbar-items a {
    font-family:"Roboto",sans-serif;
    color:#01000a;
    padding:15px;
    border-radius:2px;
    margin:12px;
    text-align:center;
    cursor:pointer;
    background:#fdfdfd;
    border:1px solid #efefef;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.navbar-items a:hover {
    background:#5558f5;
    color:#fff;
    border:1px solid #5558f5;
}

.sidebar .options {
    width:100%;
    height:40%;
}

.footer p {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    margin: 15px;
    color: #01000a;
}

.footer a {
    margin:15px;
    color: #01000a;
    text-decoration:none;
}

/*Lists.php*/
.lists-content {
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
}

.lists-content .note {
    background:rgb(255, 255, 255);
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    box-shadow:2px 2px 12px 2px #fff9f9;
    border:1px solid #efefef;
    border-radius:4px;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.note > .header-note {
    width:100%;
    height:20%;
    background:red;
}

.note > .center-note {
    width:100%;
    height:60%;
    background:blue;
}

.note > .footer-note {
    width:100%;
    height:20%;
    background:red;
}

.container {
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap:2px;
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns:300px 1fr;
    grid-template-rows:70px 500px 1fr;
    grid-template-areas:
    "header header"
    "sidebar content"
    "footer footer";
    overflow:hidden;
}

.header {
    grid-area:header;
    border-radius:2px;
    display:flex;
    border-bottom:1px solid #efefef;
}

.sidebar {
    grid-area:sidebar;
    border-radius:2px;
    background:#ffffff;
    border-right:1px solid #ebebeb;
    transition:width 0.4s;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    position:relative;
    /*left:-300px;*/
    transition:left 0.4s;
}

.content {
    grid-area:content;
    border-radius:2px;
    position:relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.footer {
    grid-area:footer;
    border-radius:2px;
    background: #efefef;
    border-top: 1px solid #d6d3d3;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
}
```

Does anyone know what's going on, or what would be causing this? Like theirs cursor pointer everywhere in the content section and I can't fix it and some of my styles aren't going into effect on my lists.php where I'm trying to add colored sections into my .note div.

Comment: Check the browser's console tab and the network tab to see if there may be any 404 errors on loading file(s). If nothing obvious there, even though I see the URL cache bust using `time()` calls, try clearing browser cache and reload.